# How to install a ruby gem on windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Sorry to ask such a basic question. I'm trying to install **tiny_tds** as explain on [this page](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds). I've tried **$ gem install tiny_tds**, I'm getting error: Syntaxt error, unexpected $undefined. If I remove $, the error becomes undefined local variable or methos "tiny_tds". I don't know where to start to install a gem. I'm using the ruby command prompt.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should try railsinstaller for windows that includes rubygems. Then `gem install tiny_tds` in the command prompt.

Comment: It looks like Rails installer is for writing rails web application. All I want is just a way to connect to sql server with tiny_tds.

Comment: With railsinstaller you'll have rubygems installed as well and it will work in Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails. tiny_tds works fine on my platform

Comment: Do I need to be at the root, i.e. C:/> or that doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Rubygems will do work for you. Go to Railsinstaller folder in start menu -> Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails -> gem install tiny_tds

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the Ruby installer depending on you systems settings (32 or 64 bit) and the ruby development kit in order to run command lines. Here is a link to the installer and a simple guide for installing the DevKit for ruby on windows (this one is to make jekyll run on windows, jekyll is other ruby gem):

Ruby Installer:
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Devkit configuration:
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html